# Copy data from Excel Sheet and Search on Webpage and Find Another Data to be pasted to Excel

Tags: excel

Basically I have all the product ID with me.

I wish search the product IDs on the webpage and find some specific data from the webpage and paste them to the excel sheet.

After I paste the product ID into the webpage, I need to press search and click on more details to obtain all the information.

Is it possible to automate this process? (1000 data is no joke :( )

Comment: Not only is it possible but a solution can easily be found in a couple minutes with google.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to make an attempt yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) and you can't solve it, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937).